# In spring mvc, headers = "x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest" in request mapping not working?

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I have two methods, one is supposed to handle login request issued by JS, another takes care of login page.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD},
    headers = "x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest")
    public @ResponseBody String login() {...}


 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
    public String getLoginPage() {......}
```

However, all the login requests seems to go to the getLoginPage method whether it has "x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest" header or not. I doubled checked http headers, it contains correct head. So it seems Spring just ignores the login method.

I've been struggling with this for a while, any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`headers` uses `=` as a delimiter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD},     
    headers = "x-requested-with=XMLHttpRequest")
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. What I don't understand is in http spec, it uses ":" as the delimiter; why Spring can't stick to it and make my life easier:).

Comment: @Bobo: How would you write `!=` condition then, as `!:`?

Answer (score 0):

```
produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

in a `@RequestMapping` (`@GetMapping`) should also work for regular XLHttpRequest and could be preferable